# Solana 1.17+, what processor should be used when instantiating ProgramTest::new()?

Tags: anchor, anchor-lang, testing, solana-program-test

I recently upgraded from Solana 1.14 to 1.17.22 and I'm not able to write rust tests that way I've previously been able to. Specifically, previously, when instantiating `ProgramTest::new` I've typically used `ProgramTest::new("program-name", program-name::ID, processor!(program-name::entry))`, but it seems as though the `process_instruction` argument changed to be one of a `builtin_function` with a different type as well (`ProcessInstructionWithContext` to `BuiltinFunctionWithContext`). I haven't been able to find any helpful documentation or examples, and am having a hard time figuring out what needs to be passed here.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error you're seeing? The upgrade process was seamless in my experience. Can you make sure you're using all 1.17 crates?